# nightwatchjs - Running tests in parallel

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, nightwatch.js

Below command should open new two browser window and run same test.

`node nightwatch.js -t test/createAdminUser.js --viewport desktop --browser chrome,chrome`

But it gives this error:

```
[Create Admin User Test] Test Suite
==========================================

Running:  Create Admin User on Stage

Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ state: 'unhandled error',
  sessionId: null,
  hCode: 1184829102,
  value:
   { additionalInformation: '\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown',
     localizedMessage: 'The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ed
ge.EdgeDriver can\'t create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{acceptSslCe
rts=true, name=Create Admin User on Stage, browserName=chrome,chrome, javascriptE
nabled=true, screenResolution=undefinedxundefined, platform=ANY}]\nBuild info: v
ersion: \'2.53.1\', revision: \'a36b8b1\', time: \'2016-06-30 17:37:03\'\nSystem
 info: host: \'NODE487\', ip: \'10.210.1.216\', os.name: \'Windows 7\', os.arch:
 \'amd64\', os.version: \'6.1\', java.version: \'1.8.0_65\'\nDriver info: driver
.version: unknown',
     supportUrl: null,
     systemInformation: 'System info: host: \'NODE487\', ip: \'10.210.1.216\', o
s.name: \'Windows 7\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'6.1\', java.version: \'
1.8.0_65\'',
     cause: null,
     suppressed: [],
     message: 'The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDr
iver can\'t create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true,
 name=Create Standard Hero Test, browserName=chrome,chrome, javascriptEnabled=tr
ue, screenResolution=undefinedxundefined, platform=ANY}]\nBuild info: version: \
'2.53.1\', revision: \'a36b8b1\', time: \'2016-06-30 17:37:03\'\nSystem info: ho
st: \'NODE487\', ip: \'10.210.1.216\', os.name: \'Windows 7\', os.arch: \'amd64\
', os.version: \'6.1\', java.version: \'1.8.0_65\'\nDriver info: driver.version:
 unknown',
     hCode: 1859305781,
     class: 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException',
     buildInformation:
      { buildRevision: 'a36b8b1',
        buildTime: '2016-06-30 17:37:03',
        releaseLabel: '2.53.1',
        hCode: 359238480,
        class: 'org.openqa.selenium.internal.BuildInfo' },
     screen: null },
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 13 }
```

Comment: you need an equals sign. --browser=chrome,chrome works on my machine.

Comment: If this worked or did not work, please let me know.